# dd-MON-yy time data does not match format

Tags: python, pandas

I know common question but sort of stuck. I believe I've gotten to the correct format specifier for the to_date function.

I have data that looks like

| date |
| --- |
| 19-SEP-22 |

I'm trying to convert it to a standard DD/MM/YYYY format

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%d-%b-%y')
df['date'] = df['date'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

I'm getting error on the first line that the time data does not match the specified format although I believe it should be correct. d for 'dd' b for 'MON' and y for 'yy' am I missing something?

Comment: It's correct indeed. What might be happening is that you have values with different formats on the date column.

Comment: Thanks, time go digging through this source file. The joys of being in data engineering are endless I tell you.

Comment: That data works fine with that code. Please make a [mre]. For specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: BTW, `to_date` should be `to_datetime`, yeah?